# I have an ArrayList with 14 values, but get IndexOutOfBounds Exception. I checked if they were null and they printed the values

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

```
int index=0;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(14);


for (index = text.indexOf("$");
  index >= 0;
  index = text.indexOf("$", index + 1))

  {
     list.add(index);   
  }

  System.out.print(list.size());


System.out.println(text.substring(list.get(12)+1,list.get(12)+8));    
System.out.println(text.substring(list.get(13)+1, list.get(13)+8));

System.out.println(text.substring(list.get(14)+1,list.get(14)+9));
System.out.println(text.substring(list.get(14)-10, list.get(14)+9));                            

String a7 = text.substring(list.get(7)+1,list.get(7)+8);
String a8 = text.substring(list.get(8)+1,list.get(8)+8);
String a9 = text.substring(list.get(9)+1,list.get(9)+8);
String a10 = text.substring(list.get(10)+1,list.get(10)+8);
String a11 = text.substring(list.get(11)+1,list.get(11)+7);
String a12 = text.substring(list.get(12)+1,list.get(12)+8);    
String a13 = text.substring(list.get(13)+1, list.get(13)+8);
String a14 = text.substring(list.get(14)+1,list.get(14)+9);
String a15 = text.substring(list.get(14)-10, list.get(14)+9);
```

> Error:
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   12, Size: 12   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)     at
>   pkgfinal.Final.main(Final.java:240)

I made sure that index 12 has a value, but I still get this error.
"text" is a scanned document

Edit:
You chose to open this file: Scan.pdf
/C:/Users/sahaj/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Final/build/classes/

11. 99

981.83

3279. 13

$3279. 13

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 
12

```
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)

at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)

at pkgfinal.Final.main(Final.java:245)
```

453

Comment: What is the content of "text"?

Comment: How do you make sure that "that index 12 has a value"?

Comment: text is a receipt that was scanned. It was told to get all instances of a dollar sign. I have checked that it has a value by just printing it to the console. It gave a value, but also an error

Comment: It's not clear what the goal is. Is the goal to find all the dollar amounts following a $?

Comment: Yes that is the goal. I have a receipt, I am looking for dollar signs and getting the values of them.

Comment: Can you provide the full output?

Comment: What does System.out.println(list.size()) print?

Comment: @mikulskibartosz I added an edit with the outputs

Comment: Hi Sahaj! Your post would be easier to read (and have a bigger chance of getting upvotes and attention) if you would make the code indented in a sensible way. Right now it is far away to the right. This is probably easy to do in you editor or IDE.

Comment: @Lii sorry I just signed up today.

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayList does not contain 14 values.

When you create a new ArrayList the Integer accepted by its constructor is the initial capacity, it does not mean that the array contains 14 nulls.

ArrayList with initial capacity contains an array of Objects with 14 empty slots, but its 'size' field is set to 0, because you have not added any elements to the ArrayList.

When you call the get method it checks whether the index < the current size of the ArrayList. If the index is greater than (or equal to) the size, it throws the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @SahajPatel are you checking that they are non-null. You have created the ArrayList with an initial size padded with null values.

Comment: no, I just System.out.println the value that they held and it worked fine, but only got the error hindering the progress

Comment: Could you show us how do you println that value? Do you use some built-in method or iterate over the ArrayList and .get() the values?

Comment: @MikulskiBartosz I honestly can't see where this is going wrong. There are 14 values stored in the array, but tells that there are only 12.

Comment: System.out.println(text.substring(list.get(12)+1,list.get(12)+8));    
^^^This was how I checked. It just printed them, instead of saving them in a string

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 12
```

so your `list` contains 12 elements, you cannot use method `list.get(12);` because `java.util.List` is zero indexable you should use `list.get(11);` to get the 12th element.

Comment: But I can access the values to index 12, along with the larger ones.

Comment: are you sure that 'text' contains at least 12 '$' character?

Comment: yes I counted 15 and all of them are recognized by the program.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact format of the input data this is what I came up with. Knowing more about the data you will allow you to simplify this logic.

```
String text = "This is a receipt $12.10 and $14.50";

ArrayList<BigDecimal> dollarAmounts = new ArrayList<>();
int index = 0;
while ((index = text.indexOf("$", index)) != -1) {
  int whitespace = text.indexOf(" ", index + 1);
  if (whitespace == -1) {
    dollarAmounts.add(new BigDecimal(text.substring(index + 1)));
  } else {
    dollarAmounts.add(new BigDecimal(text.substring(index + 1, whitespace)));
  }
  index++;
}

for (BigDecimal dollarAmount : dollarAmounts) {
  System.out.println(dollarAmount);
}
```

Your original example made a few incorrect assumptions about how ArrayList's work.

When you create an `ArrayList(14)` you are setting the backing array size to 14. An `ArrayList` is backed by an `Object[]` and when that array fills up it needs to create a larger backing array and copies all the elements from the original into it.

This is slow.

If you know you will be populating an array with 2 million objects it may be best to start it near that capacity to reduce the internal copy operations.

Comment: do you think that using array instead of array list will be better?

Comment: Since receipt data generally changes in length as more items are purchased I would say no, you would have to duplicate a lot of the work ArrayList already provides.